# Decrypting Data with CryptUnprotectData in Rust Leads to STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION Error

Tags: winapi, rust, low-level, dpapi

I'm working on a `Rust` function that receives a `&[u8]` and decrypts it using `CryptUnprotectData` from the `WinAPI`. Here's the function in question:

```rust
fn decrypt(data: &[u8]) -> Result<Vec<u8>, String> {}
```

I've successfully implemented this function, and it successfully decrypts the data using `DPAPI`.

However, I've encountered an issue when trying to free the buffer passed to `CryptUnprotectData`. I'm getting the following error:

```rust
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\main.exe` (exit code: 0xc0000374, STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION)
```

Here's the code for the function:

```rust
use winapi::{
    um::{
        winbase,
        dpapi,
        wincrypt
    },
    shared::minwindef
};

fn decrypt(keydpapi: &[u8]) -> Result<Vec<u8>, String> {
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dpapi/nf-dpapi-cryptunprotectdata
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-localfree
    // https://docs.rs/winapi/latest/winapi/um/dpapi/index.html
    // https://docs.rs/winapi/latest/winapi/um/winbase/fn.LocalFree.html

    let mut data_in = wincrypt::DATA_BLOB {
        cbData: keydpapi.len() as minwindef::DWORD,
        pbData: keydpapi.as_ptr() as *mut minwindef::BYTE,
    };
    let mut data_out = wincrypt::DATA_BLOB {
        cbData: 0,
        pbData: ptr::null_mut()
    };
    let result = unsafe {
        dpapi::CryptUnprotectData(
            &mut data_in,
            ptr::null_mut(),
            ptr::null_mut(),
            ptr::null_mut(),
            ptr::null_mut(),
            0,
            &mut data_out
        )
    };
    if result == 0 {
        return Err("CryptUnprotectData failed".to_string())
    };
    if data_out.pbData.is_null() {
        return Err("CryptUnprotectData returned a null pointer".to_string());
    }
    
    let decrypted_data = unsafe {
        Vec::from_raw_parts(data_out.pbData, data_out.cbData as usize, data_out.cbData as usize)
    };
    unsafe {
        winbase::LocalFree(data_out.pbData as minwindef::HLOCAL); // error occured here
    };
    Ok(decrypted_data)
}
```

I'd appreciate any insights or solutions to resolve this `STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION` error.

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, consider using the [`windows-sys`](https://crates.io/crates/windows-sys) or the [`windows`](https://crates.io/crates/windows) crate. Either one is much more complete than `winapi` and actively maintained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```rust
let decrypted_data = unsafe {
    Vec::from_raw_parts(data_out.pbData, data_out.cbData as usize, data_out.cbData as usize)
};
unsafe {
    winbase::LocalFree(data_out.pbData as minwindef::HLOCAL); // error occured here
};
```

This code is incorrect in two ways.

1. [`Vec::from_raw_parts()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.from_raw_parts) *takes ownership* of the allocation pointer provided; that is, it takes responsibility for freeing the allocation. If you free the allocation after creating the `Vec`, that will be a double-free.

   > The ownership of `ptr` is effectively transferred to the `Vec<T>` which may then deallocate, reallocate or change the contents of memory pointed to by the pointer at will. Ensure that nothing else uses the pointer after calling this function.
2. The allocation must have been allocated by the Rust global allocator:

   > - `ptr` must have been allocated using the global allocator, such as via
   >   the [`alloc::alloc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/alloc/fn.alloc.html) function.

Whenever you are using an `unsafe` function, you must read the safety requirements and follow all of them.

Instead of `Vec::from_raw_parts`, you should construct a non-owning *slice reference* using [`std::slice::from_raw_parts`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/fn.from_raw_parts.html), then call `to_vec()` on that slice to *copy* the data into a new `Vec`. Then, you can `LocalFree` the system-created allocation.

If you don't want to copy the data, then you must return a type that owns the Windows allocation — not a Rust `Vec`. I'm not familiar with Windows bindings, so perhaps such a type already exists, but if it does not, then write your own — a struct containing the pointer, and implementing the `Deref` trait to provide data access and the `Drop` trait to deallocate when it is no longer needed.

Comment: Changing to std::slice::from_raw_parts(...).to_vec() solved it. 
It was a great opportunity to understand Rust's ownership principles better.
And I like the idea of creating usable variable to that memory view returned from winapi, it's amazing that rust allows you to customize the behavior of Deref and Drop.
Thank you!